# Xamarin.forms ENTRY hide keyboard

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I moved from xamarin.android to xamarin.forms, don't know why, just I think more support is here, but no. I'm trying to make Entry, that will be still focused, but without showing keyboard. I have inbuilt barcode scanner with keyboard input but i was finding a lot and there is no tutorial, how can i get throught that.

There's a problem, that I don't really understand connection between Project and Project.android. In xamarin.android there was command `EditText.TextInput=0` and all was done, but now, i really don't know how to make it.

There is a lot of tutorials, helps, etc. but I tried most of it, and nothing works. Have just this:

```
<Entry x:Name="dataInput" Completed="OnBarcodeReaded"/>

private void OnBarcodeReaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
       {
           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataInput.Text))
           {
               DisplayAlert("Input", dataInput.Text, "OK");
               dataInput.Text = string.Empty;
           }
       }
```

Please, does anyone know, how to pass throught it ?
Some advice how works Projectname and Projectname.Android. Or how to read serial input, may there will be output directly from scanner. Thanks a looot :)

Comment: Does your problem resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't really understand connection between Project and
>   Project.android

In the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/deepdive?pivots=windows), it says:

- `ProjectName`– This project is the .NET Standard library project that
  holds all of the shared code and shared UI.
- `ProjectName.Android` – This project holds Android-specific code and is
  the entry point for the Android application.
- `ProjectName.iOS` – This project holds iOS-specific code and is the
  entry point for the iOS application.
- `ProjectName.UWP` – This project holds Universal Windows Platform (UWP)
  specific code and is the entry point for the UWP application.

> But how can i cooperate with Project.android and Project, if i can
>   create something in .android which i will use in xamarin.forms

No, in `Xamarin.forms` project, it holds the shared codes and UI, you can't use something(like controls) you created in .`Android` in `Xamarin.forms` project. You can use [Custom Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/), [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) and etc to customize your views or use platform specific function. You can find more in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/).

> I'm trying to make Entry, that will be still focused, but without...

You can use `Custom Renderer` to disable keyboard of `Entry` in each platform. You can have a look at [this article](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/05/19/a-keyboard-disabled-entry-control-in-xamarin-forms/). There are sample and explanations there.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't really understand connection between Project and Project.android

Project is your shared code that is reused between Android iOS UWP. Project Andriod is your specific platform code. I don't really understand what are you trying to accomplish with entry without keyboard? What scanner do you use?

Comment: I think it's called V720 Kcosit. When i'm focused on entry and press scan, it prints `Type:ean... Code:....` so i just need to hide keyboard when i'm focused on that entry. Althrought i know that ... its shared code. But how can i cooperate with Project.android and Project, if i can create something in .android which i will use in xamarin.forms

Comment: You are mixing Xamarin Forms, project code and platform specific code. In Xamarin forms you create base project. This project contains shared code. This code can be run both on Android and iOS, but you can't run this code directly. That why in Xamarin Forms creates also platform specific code that is used to compile final app for specific platform. You can call it wrapper for your shared code. If you need an app just for Android using XF is useless. XF is used for rapid app development for multiple platforms.